# shiny R: how to use for loop in shiny app

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I am trying to take the dataframe **values$df** and create another dataframe **df** by using for loop. In the for loop, I would like to display the average score of each team. Although it generates reactive outputs for **unique(values$df$team)** in output$summa2, it does not generate any outputs for what's inside the for loop. And when I add **return(df)** at the end, it only generates the first row of the dataframe, not all.

Here is what I have in the server.R file:

```
  values<- reactiveValues() 
  values$df<- data.frame()

  observeEvent(input$click_counter, {
    name<- input$name
    gender<- input$gender
    college<- input$college
    team<- input$team
    score<- as.numeric(input$score)
    rank<- 0

    new_row<- data.frame(rank,name,college,gender,team,score)

    values$df<- rbind(values$df, new_row)
    values$df<- values$df[order(values$df$score,decreasing=TRUE),]
    values$df$rank<- 1:nrow(values$df)
  })

output$summa2 <- renderPrint({
    unique(values$df$team) # this works
    for (team_name in unique(values$df$team)){ #this does NOT work
      rank<- 0
      team<- team_name
      score<- format(mean(values$df[values$df$team==team_name,]$score), digits=4)

      new_row<- data.frame(rank, team, score)

      df<- rbind(df, new_row)
      df<- df[order(df$score,decreasing=TRUE),]
      df$rank<- 1:nrow(df)
      #return(df)
    }
  })
```

And this is what I have in the ui.R file:

```
verbatimTextOutput("summa2")
```

Comment: Without the complete app, we can not reproduce the error. Hints I could give: 1) I cant see where `df` is created; `?df` is a function by default. 2) I would put the for loop calculation within the `observeEvent()` or create a new reactive or `observe()` function and pass the result to the `renderPrint()`,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the renderPrint to this:

```
output$summa2 <- renderPrint({
  df <- data.frame()
  for (team_name in unique(values$df$team)){ #this does NOT work
    local({
      rank <- 0
      team <- team_name
      score <- format(mean(values$df[values$df$team==team_name,]$score), digits=4)

      new_row<- data.frame(rank, team, score)

      df <<- rbind(df, new_row)
      df <<- df[order(df$score,decreasing=TRUE),]
      df$rank <<- 1:nrow(df)
    })
  }
  return(df)
})
```

Comment: Actually the `local({ })` shouldn't be necessary. In this case, the solution seems to be simpler - you were just returning too early.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks so much for your help :)